# maximum area of a quadrilateral with a given perimeter

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Given a quadrilateral with a given perimeter P, I need to find the one with the maximum area.
I already know that the maximum area of a rectangle with a given perimeter P the one with the max area is a square. But i have no idea how to find the maximum area when it's not a triangle.

I tried to use Bretschneider's formula:

$$S=\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b(s-c)(s-d)-\frac{1}{2}abcd[1+\cos{(\angle A+\angle C)}}]$$

but there are angles in this formula.

I also tried to use this:

$$S=\frac{1}{2}ab \sin \angle A +\frac{1}{2}cd \sin \angle C $$

I know for a fact that I need to use inequality of arithmetic and geometric means so I tried to use the second formula by using this:

$\sqrt{xy} \leq \frac{1}{2} (x+y) \ \ \ \ \ /\uparrow^2$

$xy\leq \frac{1}{4}(x+y)^2$

but agian, I have no idea what do I do with the angles.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this down:

You have the formula

$$S=\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)-\frac{1}{2}abcd[1+\cos{(\angle A+\angle C)}}]$$

which as a sum of opposing angles at $A$and $C$. The cosine of this sum is at its minimum of $-1$ when the opposite angles are s___________y.

So now you know that each pair of opposing angles has that property. Now consider the sides. With the formula reduced to

$S=\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}$

$\text{*Brahmagupta's Formula* for a cyclic quadrilateral}$

you now use AM-GM to render

$(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)\le[(1/4)((s-a)+(s-b)+(s-c)+(s-d))]^4$

with equality holding when $a=b=c=d$ for any fixed $s$. So the sides must be e___l, and you can even work out how each side is then related to $s=(a+b+c+d)/2$.

You conclude that all sides are e___l and the opposing angles are s___________y. This should be enough to determine the shape of the quadrilateral and get you s____ed away.

Comment: +1   Googling, I get the impression that this fact was part of high-school geometry.